# CircleCI Could not locate Gemfile

Tags: ruby, circleci

I have a ruby gem project, let's say this is the folder structure

```
- org-lib
  - .circleci
  - ticketing
    - ticket-management
```

so my gem is in folder `ticket-management`, and there is `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` there. and all the spec.

and this is my circleci yml

```
version: 2.1
jobs:
 ticket-management-job:
    working_directory: ~/ticketing/ticket-management
    docker:
      - image: circleci/ruby:3.0.1
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: "Install Bundle"
          command: "bundle install"
      - run:
          name: "Run Test"
          command: "bundle exec rspec spec/ticket_management_spec.rb"
workflows:
  ticket-management-workflow:
    jobs:
      - ticket-management-job
```

when i push it i got error

```
bundle install
Could not locate Gemfile

Exited with code exit status 10
CircleCI received exit code 10
```

How to fix this error? How to properly setup CI at ruby gem?

Comment: Try re-running the job with SSH (https://circleci.com/docs/ssh-access-jobs/) to see if you can locate the file. And then, as someone suggested below, set your `working_directory` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have Gemfile in the folder where you run `bundle install`.
You can debug by adding `ls` command before `bundle install` to get list files of the current folder.

Comment: there is a Gemfile in my ticket-management folder, but when i try use `ls`, it is in the `org-lib` folder, is my working_directory wrong?

Comment: try this
`working_directory: ~/org-lib/ticketing/ticket-management`